# Draft.js editor is empty

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How to test if the content of [draftjs](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js) editor is empty?

The only idea that I have now is an object comparison against the object returned from this function : `EditorState.createEmpty().getCurrentContent()`

Comment: check that out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420136/how-to-check-empty-spaces-in-draft-js-editor/68093543#68093543

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just use the [hasText](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state/#hastext) function on `ContentState` :

```
editorState.getCurrentContent().hasText()
```

Comment: Does this work with editor states that have only images etc? I have read the docs of `draftjs` and there doesn't seem to be a straight-forward way to check if editor state is empty. I think they left this as an implementation detail because it is not clearly understood what the meaning of `empty` is, maybe because even if the editor state is `empty`, it contains other info like cursor position, placeholder etc which may not be the exact kind of content we would like to check for. I could be wrong, let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is nice. But the issue is that even if the user has typed only spaces then also it will return true. How to check that case?

Answer (score 6):

```
 contentState.hasText() && contentState.getPlainText().length > 0
```

### Check

- Empty
- White Space

Answer (score 2):

```
export const isEmptyDraftJs = (rawState) => {
  if (!rawState || _.isEmpty(rawState)) { // filter undefined and {}
    return true;
  }
  const contentState = convertFromRaw(rawState);
  return !(contentState.hasText() && (contentState.getPlainText() !== ''));
};
```

I am not sure it is perfect but I use above code.

When you add just image, there is an space character so `getPlainText()` can filter only image draftJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
const text=editorState.getCurrentState().getPlainText()
return text===''
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```js
// All just you need is:
const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
const rawContentState = convertToRaw(contentState);
const text = rawContentState.blocks[0].text.trim();

//See the full code below:
   

const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');


const handleSubmit = () => {
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const rawContentState = convertToRaw(contentState);
  const text = rawContentState.blocks[0].text.trim();

  if (text === '') {
    setErrorMessage('Please enter some content before submitting.');
  } else {
    // Proceed with submission logic
    setErrorMessage('');
    // Your submission logic goes here
  }
};
```