# How to check empty spaces in draft js Editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

How i can check empty there are empty spaces in editor?
i don't want to submit form when there are empty spaces in editor.
i'm using  this function that detect is editor is empty or not but it does not detect is editor has empty spaces or not

```
contentState.hasText()
```

Comment: Do you meat the case when the editor content has only space characters and no letters?  If your editor has `foo bar` text should the form is submitted in this case?

Comment: i mean when the editor has only spaces without any character.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the editor content with two methods which you can call on the current content state. First - [hasText](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#hastext) and second [getPlainText](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#getplaintext)

Check the demo below. Here we check three different editor condition:

- is editor empty (no spaces, no letters, no other characters),
- is editor contain only space (and no other characters),
- is editor contain some text (any characters except spaces)

```js
const {Editor, EditorState} = Draft;

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
  }
  
  _handleChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  
  _checkEditorContent = () => {
    const content = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const isEditorEmpty = !content.hasText();
    const currentPlainText = content.getPlainText()
    const lengthOfEditorContent = currentPlainText.length;
    const lengthOfTrimmedContent = currentPlainText.trim().length;
    const isContainOnlySpaces = !isEditorEmpty && !lengthOfTrimmedContent;

    console.clear();
    console.log('editor empty => ', isEditorEmpty)
    console.log('editor containe only spaces => ', isContainOnlySpaces)
    console.log('editor containe some text (not only spaces) => ', !!(!isEditorEmpty && lengthOfTrimmedContent))
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-root">
        <Editor 
          placeholder="Type away :)"
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this._handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this._checkEditorContent}>
          CHECK
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'))
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.public-DraftEditor-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.7.0/Draft.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.0/Draft.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.trim() to removes all jumps and spaces then just have to check the length:

```js
if (content.getPlainText().trim().length == 0) {
  updateYourVariableToNull()
}
```

or if you're using the EditorState:

```js
editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText().trim().length
```